# Unexpected character after using send.keys - Samsung s20 device

Tags: python, appium

first off, i'm new here and it's my first steps in programming...

i have following issue, i'm trying to write a script which will send automatically text message to entered number.
After using send_keys, device entering provided digits, but after .send_keys(Keys.ENTER) it has changed to strange character

I've tried a lot of different ways but the same result.

I've also tried to set/change encoding (maybe here is a problem) but i do not how to do this in python - there is no option to set set Capability in driver, but maybe this is not a problem

plspls help me

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #import przyciskow
import time

desired_cap ={
  "deviceName": "R3CMA0BW79P",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "appPackage": "com.samsung.android.messaging",
  "activity": "com.samsung.android.messaging.ui.view.main.WithActivity",
  "app": "C:\\PROG\\SamsungMessages_11.apk"
}

driver = webdriver.Remote ("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",desired_cap)

driver.find_element_by_id('com.samsung.android.messaging:id/fab').click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('com.samsung.android.messaging:id/recipients_editor_to').send_keys('123456789')
driver.find_element_by_id('com.samsung.android.messaging:id/recipients_editor_to').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```